# How to compare two Sharepoint Lists and add Item from one list into the other one?

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint

I've tried to compare two SharePoint Online lists. Both of them have an "email" as list item and if the email is equal then it should import the list item "Steuernummer" (German word for Tax number) which is in list1 to the other list.

**Here is my Code:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using CsvHelper;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy;

namespace ImportListFromCSV {
    class Program {

static void Main() {
            // creates a new SharePoint context 
            // passing the parameters
            Uri siteUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SrcUrl"].ToString());
            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUri.ToString())) {
                Uri siteUri2 = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DestUrl"].ToString());
                using (var clientContext2 = new ClientContext(siteUri2.ToString())) {
                    // selects the list by title
                    List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Gesetzliche Vertreter");
                    List list2 = clientContext2.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Funktionaere");
                CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                    query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Steuernummer' /></OrderBy><Query></Query></View>";

                  // ListItemCollection collListItem = list.GetItems(query);
                  //  clientContext.Load(collListItem);
                    ListItemCollection collListItem2 = list2.GetItems(query);
                    clientContext2.Load(collListItem2);

               /* clientContext2.Load(collListItem,
                items => items.Include(
                item => item["Steuernummer"],
                item => item["E-Mail"]));
              */  
                clientContext2.Load(collListItem2,
                items => items.Include(
                item => item["Steuernummer"],
                item => item["Email"]));


                    clientContext2.ExecuteQuery();
                    foreach (ListItem item in collListItem2) {
                        ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo2 = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                        ListItem listItem2 = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo2);
                       
                        listItem2.SystemUpdate();
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And here is my App.config (but not with my real data of course):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SrcUrl" value="https://SourceUrlWithSteuernummer/" />
    <add key="DestUrl" value="http://DestinationUrlWithoutSteuernummer/" />
    <add key="AccountName" value="daniel.kienzl@hgv.it" />
    <add key="AccountPwd" value="Hgv12345678" />
    <add key="ListName" value="Funktionaere" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I hope someone can help me

Best regards

Daniel

Comment: I am currently doing some research on this issue, will let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: Have you found anything useful yet?

Comment: Okay, so I've found sth that brought me near the solution but it's not working yet. Maybe somebody can help me further. https://collabedit.com/298vn